# Checking For Page Logo Using Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

My question is related to showing the logo image at the top of the webpage. Something that you can see if you can go to youtube or even stackoverflow.

[image]

Is this some kind of image that we upload. And can we check for this using Selenium? Something we do if we want to check if an image is shown on a webpage?

Comment: check for the head contents in html page. You would see a tag for image in there.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get site's favicon using Selenium](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8522683/how-can-i-get-sites-favicon-using-selenium)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are talking about http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon

and you will find an answer here:
[How can I get site's favicon using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8522683/how-can-i-get-sites-favicon-using-selenium)

Answer (score -1):

You can also use the grabicon.com API if you need to get favicons for a lot of sites, programmatically. For example, this will give you a 32 pixel version of Wikipedia's logo/favicon:

```
http://api.grabicon.com/icon?domain=wikipedia.org&size=32
```

Full disclosure, I'm the creator of grabicon, but this does answer your question and it's free.

Comment: grabicon.com is paid starting from 9$/mo