# Firefox Extension FavIconUrl is super long. Any way to shrink it?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, microsoft-edge-extension

I am working on a cross-browser extension and use the "tabs API" (https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/tabs/) to store relevant information about each tab.

One of these fields is the tab's favIconUrl.

### Problem

In **Chrome & Microsoft Edge**, this field is given as a URL string and is usually **relatively short** (a few bytes).

However in **Firefox**, this is given as a `data:image/x-icon;base64` string and is **VERY long** (a couple of KB).

The problem is that I use `storage.sync` and this resource is sparse per item stored - so what takes up nothing in Chrome/Edge, is barely enough in Firefox for a single tab.

### Example (Facebook Tab)

**Chrome & Microsoft Edge:**

```
https://static.xx.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/yo/r/iRmz9lCMBD2.ico
```

**Firefox:**

```
data:image/x-icon;base64,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
```

### Ideas?

Any ideas how I can shorten this Base64 string?

Ideally, I would need some decoder that decodes base64 but keeps regular URL strings unchanged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### For others that might face the same issue in the future.

#### THIS APPROACH IS GOOD, BUT YOU RISK VIOLATING CSP DUE TO USING BLOBS... SEE VERY BOTTOM FOR BETTER SOLUTION

I ended up converting it to a blob url by modifying this answer to my needs:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/16245768/4298115

```
function convertToShortURL(input_str, sliceSize = 512) {
  if (input_str && input_str.includes("base64")) {
    input_str = input_str.split(",")[1]; // get the base64 part
    const byteCharacters = atob(input_str);
    const byteArrays = [];

    for (let offset = 0; offset < byteCharacters.length; offset += sliceSize) {
      const slice = byteCharacters.slice(offset, offset + sliceSize);

      const byteNumbers = new Array(slice.length);
      for (let i = 0; i < slice.length; i++) {
        byteNumbers[i] = slice.charCodeAt(i);
      }

      const byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);
      byteArrays.push(byteArray);
    }

    const blob = new Blob(byteArrays);
    return URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  } else {
    return input_str;
  }
}
```

#### Explanation

This function takes in an input string that you would get from `tab.favIconUrl` using the "Tabs API" and if it is a **base64 string**, will **return a short blob url** - which you can then use the same way as a url string. Otherwise, if the **input** is **already a url string or undefined** (not base64), the function simply **returns it as is**.

### BEST APPROACH

Based on:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/8498629/4298115 **(domain from url)**
2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/3880629/4298115 **(favicon from domain)**

```
function getFavIconURL(url) {
  var matches = url.match(/^https?\:\/\/([^\/?#]+)(?:[\/?#]|$)/i);
  var domain = matches && matches[1]; 
  return "http://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=" + domain;
}
```

This function simply returns the favicon url without returning a blob file.

Simple and elegant in my opinion. Cheers!